# Using dictionary comprehension to find vowels in string?

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

Assuming `S = "Tea Lemon CoffEE cAke".lower()`

```
    { x:y.count('aeoiu') for x in S.split() for y in 'aeoiu' if y in 'aeoiu' }
```

the output of this is:

```
    {'cake': 0, 'tea': 0, 'lemon': 0, 'coffee': 0}
```

Why is it giving me 0s and not the number of vowels in each word?
I'm new to python and I would appreciate some hints. Totally not looking for straight answers.

Comment: You're counting the number of occurrences of the string `'aeoiu'` which is zero for each token.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "straight answers"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want to do this:

```
{ x: sum(x.count(y) for y in 'aeoiu') for x in S.split() }
```

Which outputs:

```
{'coffee': 3, 'cake': 2, 'lemon': 2, 'tea': 2}
```

Your code was counting the number of times the string 'aeoiu' occurs in `y`, which is always zero. Also note that `for y in 'aeoiu' if y in 'aeoiu'` is redundant, you don't need the `if`.